# How do I find fields unique to data in other fields?

Tags: mysql, sql

To generalise, I have a database with a similar structure to the following:

---

```
CustomerDatabase
ProductID  | ProductName | CustomerID | Gender |
008100     | Laptop      | 1          | Male   |
008101     | Desktop     | 2          | Female |
008100     | Laptop      | 3          | Female |
008102     | Printer     | 4          | Male   |
008101     | Desktop     | 5          | Female |
```

What statement could I run to display product IDs that have only been purchased by a particular gender and not the other?

An Example result would look like:

```
ProductID | Gender | CustomerID|
008101    | Female | 2         |
008101    | Female | 5         |
```

because The product "008101" was only purchased by females and not males.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use a single `MAX` relaying on the fact the `Male` is larger then `Female` , so if the maximum one is `Female`, then its the only one.

```
select t.productid
from YourTable t
group by t.productid
having MAX(t.gender) = 'Female'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the product ids using aggregation and `having`:

```
select productid
from t 
group by productid
having min(gender) = max(gender) and min(gender) = 'F';
```

You can get the rows in the original table using a `join`, `in`, or `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select productid
      from t 
      group by productid
      having min(gender) = max(gender) and min(gender) = 'F'
     ) tf
     on t.productid = tf.productid;
```

Comment: To clarify, this will work by selecting products that have not been purchased by the other gender at all?  And it filters products purchased by both genders?

Comment: @ADP . . . Both these versions choose products that have been chosen by only females.  You can drop the comparison to `F` and get products that have only been purchased by a single gender.

Answer (score 0):

To only get the `productID`s females ordered you can do

```
select productid
from your_table
group by productid
having sum(gender = 'Male') = 0
```

and to only get the `productID` only single genders ordered you can do

```
select productid
from your_table
group by productid
having count(distinct gender) = 1
```